# how to exclude directories and file zipping a directory?

Tags: zip

I, need to zip a directory excluding some subdirectory  and file;
I used this:

```
zip -r zipfile.zip . -x ".*" -x "app/bower_components" -x "node_modules" -x "*.zip" -x "node_modules"
```

without  any success; `node_modules` is a folder in the principal one while `bower_components` is inside the folder app

Comment: what is your result and what are your expected result?

Comment: You want to exclude *all* subdirectories or only some of them ?

Answer (score 65):

I simply make a guess what you want.

```
-x ".*"
```

exclude all files beginning with a dot

do it like:

```
-x .\*
```

exclude all files (with a dot in the filename)

do it like:

```
-x \*.\*
```

--

```
-x "app/bower_components" -x "node_modules"
```

exclude this directory and all files in it

do it like:

```
-x app/bower_components/\* -x node_modules/\*
```

--

```
-x "*.zip"
```

exclude all zip-Files

do it like:

```
-x \*.zip
```

You exclude node_modules twice

Comment: thanks I got it, using various post arrived to that:  zip -r *  app/*   -x\app/bower_components/* -x\node_modules/* -x\*.zip

Comment: @arpho Your comment above should be an answer as it appears to be working for me...

Comment: -x app/bower_components/\* -x node_modules/\* doesn work for me why?

Comment: zip -r  zipped.zip . -x "public/*" This is what worked for me after adding quotes

Answer (score 34):

exclude all node_modules folders in all folders.

```
zip -r node.zip . -x "**/node_modules/*"
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the only answer that really works.

Comment: Why not `**/node_modules/**`

Comment: @JellyFilledNuts because by using /* you selecting all folders and files in path. With /** you just determinate any path but no content ... working exmp would be also /**/* at the end but its not necessary for this case

Answer (score 24):

Assuming your directory is a git repository (and judging by the question, it very likely is), you can add directories that you want to exclude to the `.gitignore` file and use the `git archive` command to zip contents of your directory:

```
git archive --format=zip HEAD -o zipfile.zip
```

In your example, the `.gitignore` file would have to look like this:

```
node_modules
app/bower_components
```

Answer (score 14):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
zip -r zipped.zip dir1/ -x */\.* *.git* \.* *.zip *.csv *.json *.rb *.bak *.swp *.back *.merge *.txt *.sh dir1/node_modules/**\* dir1/bower_components/**\* dir1/dist/**.*
```

Where following `-x` is a list of directories and file (extension) types to exclude.

Comment: Now that I know the `**\*` is for recursive exclusion. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This works perfect for me on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo zip -r /home/user/backup/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")/home_user.zip /home/user -x "*backup*" -x "*.cache*" -x "*test*"
```

Answer (score 1):

in every project skip node_modules like this:

```
for i in */; do zip -r "${i%/}.zip" "$i" -x "*/\node_modules/*" ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

In the folder you want to be zipped:

```bsh
zip -r abc.zip . -x "node_modules/**" -x "*.git/**"
```

Comment: the only answer that actually worked; thank you